# Use the Central Limit Theorem to find the value that makes an expression true.

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose you roll a standard die 2000 times and let X be the sum of the values you get.
 Using the Central Limit Theorem, for what value of **a** is P[X >= **a**] approximately equal to P[N(0,1) >= 2] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is a Binomial Distribution with n=2000, p=1/6. mean= $np$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$. By the CLT, $P(\frac{X-\frac{2000}{6}}{\sqrt{\frac{2000}{6}\frac{5}{6}}} \geq \frac{a-\frac{2000}{6}}{\sqrt{\frac{2000}{6}\frac{5}{6}}})$ or approximately $P(N(0,1) \geq \frac{a-\frac{2000}{6}}{\sqrt{\frac{2000}{6}\frac{5}{6}}})$. Then, equate the right side of the equation with 2 to solve for $a$.

Comment: Replace "or equivalently" by "is approximately".